# Using up too much quota or will I be fine?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using a simple script to pull the total number of views of a particular video onto a webpage.

As I want it as 'realtime' as possible, I have a metatag that automatically refreshes the page every 60 seconds.

My question here is, I guess every time the page refreshes that is seen as a new call and comes from my quota. As this is running 24/7 does that mean I will exceed my quota fairly quickly given I will soon reach the 10,000 mark at this rate?

Or does each page refresh not class as a call?

I want to firstly ensure I don't go over quota and it ends up disabled but more importantly not look like I'm completely taking the mick and get seen as a spammer of some sort.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: A query is a query.  It doesn't matter if it was from some human action or some automated script.  By definition, each time your task asks Google for new numbers, the query counter is incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a page refresh makes an API call, then that API call is accounted for quota usage.

Now, you say that your page refreshes at a rate of one [`Video.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint call per minute.

Therefore, during a full day (24 hours), you'll have `24 * 60 = 1440` calls to `Videos.list`.

According to the official specification of `Videos.list`, each call to this endpoint has a quota cost of 1 unit.

Consequently, if only accounting for 1440 calls to `Videos.list`, the quota cost of your page refreshing amounts to 1440 units. That's well below the allocated daily quota of 10000 units.

This implies also that the API will by no means consider you a spammer.

Comment: Thanks, you put my mind at rest. I'm not sure what I was thinking - obviously was getting 10,000 calls per day mixed up with 10,000 being the total allowed for some reason. So if I use the same API key with the same script just a different video ID so I pick up the views from that too, that would just add onto the allowance so for example I'm using 2 scripts doing the same thing but picking up 2 different view totals from 2 different videos, the total in the day would just be 1440 x 2?

Comment: I'm a music producer and youtube has recently become a good platform for me so I'm wanting to build a mini 'web app' for my own use to summarize the total views for quick reference. I have a large library of uploaded videos but am concentrating on the top3 that are doing well.

Comment: Please bear in mind that other API calls have [very much different quota costs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost). For example, having allocated a daily amount of 10000 units of quote, one is allowed to upload only 6 videos by means of the [`Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) API endpoint (if not accounting for other kinds API calls). That's because `Videos.insert` is very expensive: 1600 units of quota per call.

Comment: Yes I did read that but I will literally only ever be pulling in the total views of a video.

Comment: One more thing: if your daily quota of 10000 units is not enough for your work, you may well apply to Google for a [quota extension](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form). But do note that, based on the experience of users of this forum, Google's answer does not necessarily come shortly.

Comment: Thanks, for now the calculations work out that I'll be well below the quota but I will make it a matter of course to monitor it.

Comment: Now, to respond to the question (quote): *if I use the same API key with the same script just a different video ID so I pick up the views from that too, that would just add onto the allowance so for example I'm using 2 scripts doing the same thing but picking up 2 different view totals from 2 different videos, the total in the day would just be 1440 x 2?* ...

Comment: ... the short answer is yes. The longer one is as follows: quota accounting is done per Google project. Thus if you have created a Google project (via Google's Developers Console), and have created an API key associated to that project, from the perspective of the API (and its quota accounting operation), it does not matter whether you call say the same API endpoint twice with different request parameters or with identical ones: two calls are accounted as two calls, thus their aggregated quota cost is twice the quota cost of that API call.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.